# How Do I Add Extra Info To A Corda Account?

Tags: corda

I have implemented parties as accounts on nodes in order address salability costs.

I can retrieve a list of accounts from the node but I can't identify the type of account as there is no such field in the AccountInfo class.

For instance, I need to identify which accounts are "suppliers" and which are "distributors".

Since I can't extend the accounts and add an "accountType" property, the only option seems to be to create an extra table with a foreign key constraint linked to the UUID of the account table.

1. What would that look like using the Corda SDKs?
2. Assuming that I have an extra table, how do I make sure that this data is created when the account is created?
3. How do I make sure that this data is copied when I share the account with a different node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All are great questions,

Off the top of my head:

1. Create a state `UserProfile` which has:
   a. `UUID`
   b. `issuer`
   c. `accountType`
2. It should have 2 commands: `Create` / `Update`.
3. The contract should check (for both commands):
   a. There should be a reference state of type `AccountInfo` in the transaction.
   b. `UserProfile.UUID` must match `AccountInfo.UUID`.

   So the above 2 conditions insure that you cannot create/update a `UserProfile` without first creating the related `AccountInfo`.
4. The `CreateUserProfile` flow will:
   a. Call `CreateAccount` flow and get the `UUID`.
   b. Use that account as reference state and its `UUID` to construct and create the related `UserProfile`.
   c. Obviously, if you need the above 2 actions to be atomic, you can't use the accounts library ready flows and you have to see what `CreateAccount` flow does (i.e. create output `AccountInfo`, generate the mapping between the `UUID` and the public key of the accounts, etc...) and do it in your flow.
5. Same when sharing a `UserProfile`, you'd have to call the accounts library sub-flow that shares an account and its keys, then you add your code that shares the `UserProfile` state.
6. This way you can add whatever fields you want to `UserProfile` and query by them, and since the `UUID` is matching between `UserProfile` and the account (i.e. `AccountInfo`), you'll always know which `UserProfile` belongs to which account and vice versa.
7. Obviously, your `UserProfile` issuer must make sure that you can only have one `UserProfile` per account.

It's a lot of work to achieve your simple requirement :-/
Hope we get other answers, because I'm curious too.

Comment: Using slightly different names I implemented the answer here https://github.com/opticyclic/corda-account-states-demo